# SSRS: Multi-value parameter with repeated values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm having issues with multi-value parameters. I was expecting I could load distinct values for the label and value combination from the default dataset but it's not working.

I have a query that looks like this:

```
Id  Name   Col1   Col2
1   Foo    aaa    ddd
1   Foo    xxx    sss
1   Foo    yyy    zzz
2   Bar    bbb    eee
3   Huh    ccc    fff
```

And want to grab the ID - Name combo from the dataset. Ideally, the results would be:

```
Value Label
1     Foo
2     Bar
3     Huh
```

However, the actual results are:

```
Value Label
1     Foo
1     Foo
1     Foo
2     Bar
3     Huh
```

EDIT: I consider this a poor solution, but made a new dataset only to collect the fields as I needed them and populate the parameter dropdown list. It's not the prettiest outcome, but should work until I find a proper way to do it.

Some of my colleagues are telling me this is the *only* way to do it, so I have to create a new data set every time I want to fill a new multi-value parameter from a query... Please tell me if it's actually the way to do it, I find it extremely inefficient.

Comment: Unfortunately you do have to create a separate dataset for your parameter values. Datasets used to populate parameters are executed when the report opens. Datasets used during main report processing are only executed when you hit "View Report" hence why they can't be referenced before. Just be careful to make your parameter query as efficient as possible, I've often seen reports bogged down by parameter queries where the dev has just copied the entire main dataset and wrapped a select distinct round it.

Comment: Your colleagues are quite correct. You should create separate datasets for each of the parameters you want to populate, in addition to the main dataset that will present data to your report. Note that the parameter datasets should only return the data required to fill the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a dataset for each parameter in order to feed it properly.